# Rails elegantly storing metadata for text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My app has thousands (maybe millions?) of models, let's call them Paragraphs, that contain text.  The primary use of that text is to display it on a webpage.  Sometimes that text is searched over for various other reasons too.

Some of the words in some of these paragraphs have associated metadata, like formatting, hyperlinks or other data-attributes that have meaning for my javascript in the front end.

Right now, I'm just sticking the ultimate html tags straight into the text, so it ends up being stored like this:

`<strong>Jimmy</strong> is walking his <a href="somewhere">dog</a> which is <span class="something" data-metadata_id="2343">brown</span>.`

This works well for the primary purpose of displaying the text, but is very ugly when I want to search over my text, or do other processing on it.  Is there a better way?  Is there a gem that handles this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense to put both versions in your database: a display one and an index one. Disk is cheap. Especially if you're using Solr or similar (very recommended if you're doing string search), you can store (but not index) the HTML, and index (but not store) the plain text version, in two different fields of the same record.

Comment: I was heading that way as it's cleaner.  I still have some reservation around what the code might look like when I want to process the text further and add additional tags to it.  Eg if I wanted to later on mark up all instances of the word 'walking' in my app, the app would search the clean version, find the word, then search the marked up version again, taking care that the word 'walking' it finds there is in the 'real' text rather than the metadata, then wrap it.  Still seems a bit ugly, but is that the best I can do?

Comment: There is an alternative, converting the markup into standoff format (plain text plus annotations with start/end position), but that also carries its own headaches with it.

Comment: Also, sometimes the metadata references other database objects through their ids.  This approach seems subpotimal for handling changes to those objects - for example if they get deleted.  But it also seems very expensive to create a new model/record for every word in my database.

Comment: I've decided to try a hybrid approach for now.  I'll store both the clean and marked up strings.  I'll also create a new Annotation model, with one instance per marked up term.  It'll contain the string that it anchors to, and the integer position of that string in the paragraph, and will have a reference to the other database objects.  Callbacks will hopefully ensure that if the other database objects change, or the paragraph itself changes, all relevant related objects are updated.  Thanks for the brainstorm!